# I need help on Xerox VersaLink C405

Tags: printer, hardware-detection, replacement

I need some help with "How to replace the Transfer Unit Kit" from the printer Xerox Versalink C405
I tried looking for some solution, but I didn't find a proper one.
If someone could help me, I would gladly appreciate the efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found these that might help your situation.

Here is how to replace the transfer roller: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bS3bBwfxzmw

Here is how to replace the transfer belt: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqrUB0Ivy6g

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.